# How to calculate distance travelled , speed , duration in iOS devices with M7 Co-processor?

Tags: ios, ios7, core-motion, apple-m7

How to calculate distance travelled , speed , duration in iOS devices with M7 Co-processor?

I have referred apple's CMMotionActivityManager document 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013503

which provides access to motion data stored by device, the data which we get is something like this :

CMMotionActivity @ 14074.912282,&lt;startDate,2014­03­03 10:09:40

+0000,confidence,1,unknown,0,stationary,0,walking,1,running,0,automotive,0&gt;

CMMotionActivity @ 14077.466468,&lt;startDate,2014­03­03 10:09:43

+0000,confidence,0,unknown,0,stationary,0,walking,0,running,1,automotive,0&gt;

CMMotionActivity @ 14080.024116,&lt;startDate,2014­03­03 10:09:46

+0000,confidence,1,unknown,0,stationary,0,walking,0,running,1,automotive,0&gt;

CMMotionActivity @ 14082.582084,&lt;startDate,2014­03­03 10:09:48

+0000,confidence,2,unknown,0,stationary,0,walking,0,running,1,automotive,0&gt;

So, without using GPS /relying only on M7 data can I calculate(eg. for Running) Distance travelled, Duration of Run, Speed etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `CMMotionActivity` class only supplies information regarding the motion activity type of the user. The iOS motion framework provides abstraction between the hardware and the software API so that regardless of whether a device is equipped with an M7 or not, you should use the same API: [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/cmmotionmanager_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Good Luck!